# using koin-test and mocking object tools

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, koin

I am new to unit testing in android. My project is with MVVM and I use Koin as dependency injection/service locater tool.
I started to use koin-test for unit testing, my question is do I still need to use mocking object tools like mockito, mockK..etc? As far as I understand it is no but I need confirmation.

Comment: Modify your subject/question line to Question format.  Lead with your question then provide the background.